# Coffeescript syntax highlighting in the browser

Tags: coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, markdown, iced-coffeescript

I am looking to create a really simple in-browser IDE for CoffeeScript.  Basically a text box and a submit button, for now.  All the code will then be submitted to the server for execution.

One thing I did want, is a syntax highlighting in the browser as the person type.  Something liked Iced Coffee for Sublime Text.  Is there a way to do this syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try embedding the [ACE editor](http://ace.ajax.org/) in your page. It has many nice color themes for the syntax highlighting and seems to support CoffeeScript (try the CoffeeScript document and mode in their [kitchen sink demo](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but you could always use CodeMirror, its what the jsfiddle uses.